# The right use of conjunctions as and when

Tags: grammar

Recently I came across such sentences in Murphy's grammar:

> My camera was stolen **when** I was in the beach.

and

> I used to live near the sea **when** I was a child.

In these two sentences " when" was the only right conjunction to use. Why can't we use the conjunction "as" here, if it has the meaning "at the same time as"?

Comment: in the beach -> at the beach ?

Comment: Not sure why you are saying **when** is the "**only** right conjunction to use". Were there choices to choose from? **While** would be another correct subordinating conjunction you could use.

Comment: We had to choose between when and as.

Comment: It was on the beach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say "I finished it as he came in" to mean "I finished it just at the same (point of) time that he came in".

In your two examples, it is not appropriate as you want to refer to a **period** of time. Here are equivalents:

> My camera was stolen during the (period of) time that I was at the beach.

Note that you must use "at", not "in", because the beach is not considered to include the air above it.

> I used to live near the sea during the (period of) time that I was a child.

Comment: @Fatimahon: You're welcome. If my answer resolved your question, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Fatimahon: For every question you ask, you can choose to accept one of the posted answers if you feel it best resolves your question, regardless of how other people vote on them. You have indeed successfully accepted an answer on each of the questions you asked, which is indicated to you by the green tick.

Comment: ThNk you for the reply, I was not sure if I pressed the right button.

Comment: But the Oxford dictionary says that `as` means `during the time that` https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as

Comment: @CITBL: I'm a native speaker and I know what I wrote is correct. Too bad your lexicon is inaccurate.

Comment: @user21820 Glad for you. But it's not my lexicon. It's from the Oxford dictionary.